# SSRS filter with Multi parameter text

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssms

I have a text parameter called @Date and I'd like to be able to write for example 2017, 2016 in the parameter textfield and filter the data on these two years. I can filter the sql-query when just 1 year is written but I can't figure out how to do it with multiple values.

I appreciate all help, and if you think I am doing this too difficult , it'd be good to know. Thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to use a multi select parameter and have different years as the available values?

Comment: Set the parameter as multivalue and use IN (@Date) in your query.

Comment: @iamdave I could but as the years go by someone will have to add and delete the values which I dont think is an option :/ Maybe if I could get distinct years from query

Comment: @niktrs I get an error saying there is something wrong near syntax (at-sign)Date
    WHERE (x.Ar IN (at-sign)Date)

Comment: You can base the multi select parameter options off a dataset that returns the Year values you need based on a SQL Script that references the current date.

Comment: That worked @iamdave And for IN to work I had to put the parameter inside ( ) ^^ Thanks both of u :)